# Парсер на PHP. CURL

Tags: php, парсер, curl, phpquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, думаю для профи вопрос простой

```
    <?php
require_once 'curl.php';
require_once 'phpQuery/phpQuery.php';

$curl= new Curl();
//$query='имя'; //для поисковика прописать в след строку через . $query
$response = $curl->get('https://x-river.ru/cat/equipment/tents/'); //страница с которой парсим 
$doc= phpQuery::newDocument($response->body);

$product=$doc->find('.tt-price'); //класс родителя в котором ищем
foreach ($product as $product) {
$pq= pq($product);
echo $pq->find('.item-price')->text() . '<br>'; //класс который выводим с переносом строки
}

?>
```

В этой конструкции идет обращение к классу, а
как реализовать получения ссылок текстом? (img src или href)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$products = $doc->find('.tt-product-listing.row col-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3');

foreach ($products as $product) {
   $pq = pq($product);
   echo $pq->find('.tt-title a')->attr("href") . '<br>'; //ссылка
   echo $pq->find('.tt-img img')->attr("src") . '<br>'; //картинка
}
```